# Drupal database input text and query database

Tags: jquery, database, drupal

I am trying to build a module that has a text input and a submit button.
I want the submit button to query a simple table in the database with part numbers
and a price for the part numbers, then display the price for the part numbers.

I have been trying for weeks as I am a beginner.

Is it best to build a custom module or is this possible using views?

I am using drupal 7

Comment: views. by the sound of this there is no need for a custom module. Just make a new data type, add the necessary fields, then using a view you set up the necessary filters. There are tons of documents on drupal, so finding the way to do this is pretty easy via google. Ask here on SO when you get stuck. But this is way too broad to give as an answer

Answer (score 0):

> You can use views only. add field and filter criteria

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I ended up writing my own module for it as it was a good learning experience. I used a form with a text box and submit button which then returned a table_theme with the results.